# Mvc DropDownlist Semicolon issue with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

This is the code am using to bind my drop down and razor is expecting`;` at the end as mentioned below

```
@{
   ViewBag.test = Model.Sample.Select(o => new SelectListItem
   {
    Text = o.Name,
    Value = o.sampleId.ToString()
   }
   );
   }
```

But when drop down is rendered am getting `;` next to my Drop down in UI

if I remove the semicolon am getting yellow screen compilation error

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Post some part of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not rendering any dropdown in this code snippet. All you are doing is assigning a value to `ViewBag.test`, and yes, there should be a `;` at the end for this to be valid C# code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.test = Model.Sample.Select(o => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = o.sampleId.ToString(),
        Text = o.Name,
    });
}
```

What you should do is to remove the `;` that you most probably left after the `@Html.DropDownList` helper call.

Also bear in mind that setting `ViewBag` values inside a view is bad practice. Using `ViewBag` is bad practice, but that's another story (see below). What you *should* do is assign this value inside the controller action rendering the view. It is not the view's responsibility to be fetching data. A view's responsibility is to display data that is sent to it under the form of a strongly typed view model which is created inside the controller action.

So to recap:

You start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action populating and passing this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    IEnumerable<SomeDomainModel> data = ... hit your DAL to retrieve the model

    // Now build a view model
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Items = data.Select(o => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = o.sampleId.ToString(),
        Text = o.Name,
    });

    // pass the view model to the view
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally you have a corresponding strongly typed view to the view model you designed earlier:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items)
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin. In my scenario am doing things dynamically getting Few values using reflection and all as i don know column names. What would be the best approach in MVC for dynamic Sections ?